# How to pass the value of a variable to the standard input of a command?

Tags: security, bash, stdin

I'm writing a shell script that should be somewhat secure, i.e., does not pass secure data through parameters of commands and preferably does not use temporary files. How can I pass a variable to the standard input of a command?

Or, if it's not possible, how can I correctly use temporary files for such a task?

Comment: Can a attacker change `$PATH` ? So that `cat` can be replaced be `/bin/cat "$@" | tee /attacker/can/read/this/file`

Comment: In case you came here from a duplicate, you probably tried `variable=$("$something" | command)` where you wanted `variable=$(echo "$something" | command)`

Answer (score 102, accepted):

### Simple, but error-prone: using `echo`

Something as simple as this will do the trick:

```
echo "$blah" | my_cmd
```

Do note that this may not work correctly if `$blah` contains `-n`, `-e`, `-E` etc; or if it contains backslashes (bash's copy of `echo` preserves literal backslashes in absence of `-e` by default, but will treat them as escape sequences and replace them with corresponding characters even without `-e` if optional XSI extensions are enabled).

### More sophisticated approach: using `printf`

```
printf '%s\n' "$blah" | my_cmd
```

This does not have the disadvantages listed above: all possible C strings (strings not containing NULs) are printed unchanged.

Comment: Perhaps you can add `printenv blah | my_cmd` to this answer?

Comment: @mallwright printenv works only for exported variables.

Answer (score 282):

Passing a value to standard input in Bash is as simple as:

```
your-command <<< "$your_variable"
```

Always make sure you put quotes around variable expressions!

> Be cautious, that this will probably work only in `bash` and will not work in `sh`.

Comment: Herestrings `<<<` are not guaranteed to be available, they are not in POSIX base, as far as I know.  They will work as expected, as long as your only running them in `bash`.  I only mention it, because they OP said 'shell' not specifically 'bash'.  Although he did tag the question with `bash`... so this still is obviously an acceptable answer.

Comment: While this may be the case, sensitive information is likely to be more easily leaked if using the `echo` method due to the creation of a pipe. The herestring command will be processed entirely by `bash`, although in this situation (as as noted) you had better know that it will work on your bash, otherwise any error message produced as a result of not supporting herestrings would also leak said information.

Comment: @StevenLu Wait, `echo` is a built-in. No pipe there, right? It's Unix, but it can't be *that much Unix*.

Comment: @CamiloMartin I don't know if bash will take e.g. `printf "abc" | cmd` and treat it the same as `cmd <<< "abc"`...

Comment: @StevenLu `printf '%s\n' "$var"` produces the same results as `echo "$var"` but won't break if, e.g., `var=-en`, and doesn't even require bash.

Comment: @CamiloMartin Yeah I caught myself and edited my comment

Comment: I tried this with the characters " and ! in the string. It failed. I tried again using """$your_variable""" instead and it worked.

Comment: I think this is the only method shown on this question where the environ doesn't get passed though the process table at any point

Comment: Note also that a newline is appended to the string for here strings.

Comment: One disadvantage I found to this syntax is that piping output from the first command into further commands isn't as intuitive as what you'd get with `echo "$your_variable" | command1 | command2`. What would the syntax be with here strings in this case?

Comment: @chunk_split you could put the here string at the beginning of the command if you prefer: `<<< "$your_variable" command1 | command2`

Answer (score 25):

```
(cat <<END
$passwd
END
) | command
```

The `cat` is not really needed, but it helps to structure the code better and allows you to use more commands in parentheses as input to your command.

Comment: But this method allows you to pass multiple lines to your command and also allows spaces in the `$passwd`

Comment: This is the best answer so far that does not leak variable contents to pipe or  process snooping.

Answer (score 22):

Note that the '`echo "$var" | command` operations mean that standard input is limited to the line(s) echoed.  If you also want the terminal to be connected, then you'll need to be fancier:

```
{ echo "$var"; cat - ; } | command

( echo "$var"; cat -   ) | command
```

This means that the first line(s) will be the contents of `$var` but the rest will come from `cat` reading its standard input.  If the command does not do anything too fancy (try to turn on command line editing, or run like `vim` does) then it will be fine.  Otherwise, you need to get really fancy - I think `expect` or one of its derivatives is likely to be appropriate.

The command line notations are practically identical - but the second semi-colon is necessary with the braces whereas it is not with parentheses.

Comment: `( echo "$LIST"; cat - ) | sed 1q` this works for me but I need to press ctrl d when I run this script?

Comment: Yes; the `cat -` continues to read from the keyboard until EOF or interrupt, so you need to tell it EOF by typing control-D.

Comment: is there a way around EOF? sed needs cat

Comment: You don't have to use `cat` at all if you don't want terminal input, as in the first line.  Or you can use `cat` to list a file.  Or ... If you want the command to read terminal input, you have to tell it when it has reached the end of the input.  Or you could use `( echo "$var"; sed /quit/q - ) | command`; this continues until you type a line containing 'quit'.  You can be endlessly inventive with how you handle it.  Beware the old urban legend of a program that stopped working when the users began working with Ecuador.  They'd type in the name of the capital, Quito, and the program exited.

Comment: OK if you say so.  But why not just `echo "$LIST" | sed 1q | ...`?  It all depends on what you're about.  The `<<EOF` notation should require an EOF at the start of a line on its own somewhere down the file.  I'd not use it, I think — but I'm still not sure what you're trying to achieve.  A simple `echo "$LIST" | command` or `echo $LIST | command` will probably suffice in practice (and it is important that you know the significance of the difference between the two).

Comment: `echo "$LIST" | head -n1` works but `echo "$LIST" | sed 1q` did not?

Comment: Don't know; they should be equivalent.

Answer (score 20):

This robust and portable way has already appeared in comments. It should be a standalone answer.

```
printf '%s' "$var" | my_cmd
```

or

```
printf '%s\n' "$var" | my_cmd
```

Notes:

- It's better than `echo`, reasons are here: [*Why is `printf` better than `echo`?*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/108618)
- `printf "$var"` is wrong. The first argument is format where various sequences like `%s` or `\n` are *interpreted*. To pass the variable right, it must not be interpreted as format.
- Usually variables don't contain trailing newlines. The former command (with `%s`) passes the variable as it is. However tools that work with text may ignore or complain about an incomplete line (see [*Why should text files end with a newline?*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25322168/10765659)). So you may want the latter command (with `%s\n`) which appends a newline character to the content of the variable. Non-obvious facts:

  - Here string in Bash (`<<<"$var" my_cmd`) does append a newline.
  - Any method that appends a newline results in non-empty stdin of `my_cmd`, even if the variable is empty or undefined.

Answer (score 16):

I liked [Martin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775548/how-can-pass-the-value-of-a-variable-to-the-standard-input-of-a-command/4775845#4775845), but it has some problems depending on what is in the variable. This

```
your-command <<< """$your_variable"""
```

is better if you variable contains `"` or `!`.

Comment: But why? Also, I can't reproduce any problems: `foo1=-; foo2='"'; foo3=\!; cat<<<"$foo1"; cat<<<"$foo2"; cat<<<"$foo3"` works fine for me. What exactly do the three `"` do? AFAIK you are just prepending and appending an empty string.

Comment: Try something real. Like your command is ssh somehost. and your variable is a shell script.

Comment: This seems to append a newline

Comment: `"""foo"""` is treated **exactly** the same way as `"foo"` by the bash parser. `""` is just an empty quote pair -- starting and ending a quoted string without any content within it; so you have `"$your_variable"` concatenated with an empty quoted string at the front and end.

Comment: Granted, `!` (even when double-quoted) causes a lot of problems in interactive shells with history expansion turned on in general, but that's a good reason to turn history expansion _off_, so interactive shells parse the code the same way ones running scripts do.

Comment: (why does `!` behave in a way that doesn't follow the rule I described above? Because history expansion happens _before regular parsing even starts_; it's a very messy feature, and everyone's better off if it's just disabled in the first place).

Answer (score 11):

As per [Martin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775548/how-can-pass-the-value-of-a-variable-to-the-standard-input-of-a-command/4775845#4775845), there is a Bash feature called *[Here Strings](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Strings)* (which itself is a variant of the more widely supported *Here Documents* feature):

> 3.6.7 Here Strings
>
> A variant of here documents, the format is:
>
> ```
> <<< word
> ```
>
> The word is expanded and supplied to the command on its standard
> input.

Note that Here Strings would appear to be Bash-only, so, for improved portability, you'd probably be better off with the original Here Documents feature, as per [PoltoS's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775548/how-can-pass-the-value-of-a-variable-to-the-standard-input-of-a-command/4775612#4775612):

```
( cat <<EOF
$variable
EOF
) | cmd
```

Or, a simpler variant of the above:

```
(cmd <<EOF
$variable
EOF
)
```

You can omit `(` and `)`, unless you want to have this redirected further into other commands.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
echo "$variable" | command
```

Comment: but wouldn't the contents $variable show up in e.g. the output of `ps -u` when echo is running?

Comment: no it won't. `echo` is a built-in, so there is no process to show in ps

Comment: Beware spaces in your variable: `echo "$variable"` is better.

Comment: that's right, bash will eat double spaces, smarter shells won't

Comment: @unbeli I guess you are referring to Zsh here. It may be "smarter" in that it does what you mean in this scenario; but that's at the expense of sacrificing Bourne shell compatibility, which is quite unfortunate. To my mind, learning to correctly quote values is superior in the long run. Anyway, this question is tagged [tag:bash], so the behavior of other shells is tangential at best.

Answer (score 0):

If you came here from a duplicate, you are probably a beginner who tried to do something like

```
"$variable" >file
```

or

```
"$variable" | wc -l
```

where you obviously meant something like

```
echo "$variable" >file
echo "$variable" | wc -l
```

(Real beginners also forget the quotes; [usually use quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable) unless you have a specific reason to omit them, at least until you understand quoting.)

Comment: Tangentially, counting how many lines there are in a string is often also an antipattern; see [useless use of `wc`.](https://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#wc)

Comment: `"$variable"` is not a syntax error if the `variable` contains a valid command, like the text `echo` or `git-commit` (though usually don't store a command in a variable, either; see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)