# Convert a text string in bash to array

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, ksh

How do i convert a string like this in BASH to an array in bash!

I have a string **str** which contains **"title1 title2 title3 title4 title5"** 
(space seperated titles)

I want the str to modified to an array which will store each title in each index.

Comment: If your titles have no spaces, you can use: `array=( $string )` (no quotes for `$string`). If your titles include spaces... well... it depends on how they are formed.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

In order to convert the string to an array, say:

```
$ str="title1 title2 title3 title4 title5"
$ arr=( $str )
```

The shell would perform word splitting on spaces unless you quote the string.

In order to loop over the elements in the thus created array:

```
$ for i in "${arr[@]}"; do echo $i; done
title1
title2
title3
title4
title5
```

Comment: FYI, this will not work for Zsh; see http://zsh.sourceforge.net/FAQ/zshfaq03.html

Comment: To do in zsh to your point @anishpatel you'll need to do this : > setopt shwordsplit; carry out the command you want to do; unsetopt shwordsplit

Answer (score 6):

Another method using read:

```
read -a array <<< $str
```

Comment: what does `<<<` do?

Comment: redirects the variable: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4775845/390913

Comment: What is the difference between readarray vs read -a

Answer (score 0):

I am in an unfortunate position where I have a long-standing shell script that is upgrading from internally using scalar variables to using arrays.  *But*, users are also allowed to set those variables themselves, optionally, with a file that is sourced on startup.

*So*, I needed to make a way to conditionally convert a scalar to an array, depending on whether the user's sourced script is declared in the new way *or* the old way.

My solution is overkill for the simple case above, but I wanted to document it for others looking for this solution, because it was non-trivial coming up with something that handled my use case.

The only way I've come up with to reliably handle all options safely is thus:

```
convert_array() {
        __array_name="$1"; shift
        __declaration="$(declare -p "$__array_name" 2>/dev/null)"
        if [ -z "${__declaration}" ]; then
                # variable is not set
                eval "${__array_name}=()"
        elif [ "$(echo "${__declaration}" | grep -c '^declare \-a')" -eq 0 ]; then
                # variable is not an array
                __existing_value="$(eval echo "\${$__array_name}" | sed -e 's,^[[:space:]]*,,' -e 's,[[:space:]]*$,,')"
                unset "${__array_name?}"
                IFS=" " read -r -a "${__array_name?}" <<< "${__existing_value}"
        fi
}
```

It cleanly handles all cases: existing variable, existing array, and not set at all.

Also note that while this may seem like overkill:

`__existing_value="$(eval echo "\${$__array_name}" | sed -e 's,^[[:space:]]*,,' -e 's,[[:space:]]*$,,')"`

...it handles the case that most people are building their sourced configurations something like this:

```
ADDITIONAL_OPTIONS="${ADDITIONAL_OPTIONS} -Xmx2g"
ADDITIONAL_OPTIONS="${ADDITIONAL_OPTIONS} -Dsome.property=foo"
```

In these cases, the `$ADDITIONAL_OPTIONS` variable will start with a space.  If you know your inputs won't need trimming, that bit is unnecessary.

```
test_foo() {
        convert_array FOO
        for VAR in "${FOO[@]}"; do
                echo "var=$VAR"
        done
}

$ FOO="foo bar baz"
$ test_foo
var=foo
var=bar
var=baz
$ unset FOO
$ test_foo
$ FOO=(foo bar baz "something with spaces")
$ test_foo
var=foo
var=bar
var=baz
var=something with spaces
```